# Prove $\lim(s_n \cdot t_n) = (\lim s_n)\cdot(\lim t_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

$$\lim(s_n\cdot t_n) = (\lim s_n)\cdot(\lim t_n)$$

I wrote their formal definition with $\sqrt{\epsilon}$. Because in the end, when I multiply them, I want to found $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ . $\sqrt{\epsilon}$
= $\epsilon$. But I could not obtain $|s_n - S| . |t_n - T|$. How can I obtain that?

Comment: What do you mean by "Define"? This is a theorem, not a definition.

Answer (score 1):

*Fact 1: A convergent sequence of the number real is bounded.*

*Fact 2:* Let $\lbrace s_n\rbrace\rightarrow s$ so, if $\varepsilon>0$ there existe $N_1>0$, such that for all $n\geq N_1$, implies $|s_n-s|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$.

*Fact 3:* Let $\lbrace t_n\rbrace\rightarrow t$ so, if $\varepsilon>0$ there existe $N_2>0$, such that for all $n\geq N_2$, implies $|t_n-t|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$.

Now

\begin{align}
|s_nt_n-st|&\leq |t_n||s_n-s|+|s||t_n-t|\\
\end{align}
Since $\lbrace t_n\rbrace$ is bounded, there exist $K>0$, such that $|t_{n}|\leq K$, and let $M:=Sup\lbrace K,|s|\rbrace$, now:
\begin{align}
|s_nt_n-st|&\leq |t_n||s_n-s|+|s||t_n-t|\\
&< M\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}+M\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}=\varepsilon.
\end{align}
For all $n>max\lbrace N_1,N_2\rbrace$

Comment: I did this. But in the end I found $|t_n(s_n - s)| + |s(t_n - t)|$. $(s_n - s)$ and $(t_n - t)$ are less than $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, okay. But then? Can you help me a little more?

Comment: After that, I guess we will obtain $\sqrt{\epsilon} . (t_n + s)$

Comment: @ibraslnn I already modified the answer